# How to programmatically deselect a ListViewItem in c++/cx?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have a `ListView` with `SelectionMode` set to `Single` in XAML and want to deselect the selected item programmatically in the code-behind, which I tried to accomplish by this line in the `MenuFlyout->Closed` event Handler (every `ListViewItem` has a `MenuFlyout` attached to it):

```
NotationListView->SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and the app crashes. Any other value works and selects the corresponding `ListViewItem`, but `-1` just doesn't do what I expected.

How can I do this?

### EDIT: my current workaround

#### XAML definition of `ListView` (shortened):

```
<ListView x:Name="NotationListView" 
    SelectionMode="None" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
    ItemClick="NotationListView_ItemClicked"/>
```

#### C++/CX definition of NotationListView_ItemClicked() (shortened):

```
ListViewItem^ item = (ListViewItem^) ((TextBlock^) e->ClickedItem)->Parent;
item->Foreground = ref new SolidColorBrush(Colors::Green);
Flyout::ShowAttachedFlyout(item);
selectedItem = item;
```

`selectedItem` is just a variable declared in the xaml.h file that stores the selected Item. That way, I can use it easily in Click-EventHandlers of the `MenuFlyoutItems`.
Now you may notice that I don't have any way of accessing the index of the clicked Item, which I desperately need. But because all the `ListViewItems` are created programmatically, I can just add this to the end of the creation:

```
auto items = NotationListView->Items;
Box<unsigned int>^ indexBox = ref new Box<unsigned int>(items->Size);
item->Tag = indexBox;
items->Append(item);
```

Now I get the Index of every item simply with the line

```
unsigned int i = ((Box<unsigned int>^)selectedItem->Tag)->Value;
```

#### C++/CX definition of NotationFlyout_Closed():

this is as easy as it gets.

```
if (selectedItem){
    selectedItem->Foreground = ref new SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black);
    selectedItem = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property you need will depend on how you have implemented the ListView. Also, make sure you have used the correct settings you intended to use.

[image: Table describing how you can use a ListView]

Source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using single-selection-mode. I was already able to programmatically select an item by using `NotationListView->SelectedIndex = 5;`, but deselecting is the Problem for me. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Does this work for you now?     NotationListView->SelectedIndex = -1; You also might have to use    NotationListView->SelectedItem = null if you need to deselect the item.

Comment: Nope, I tried both, and both crash the app. I found a workaround, though. I set `SelectionMode` to None in XAML and made the items clickable. In the `ItemClicked` event Handler, I save the clicked Item to a variable, and set its foreground to a different colour to show which item got selected. Because the `ListViewItems` are created programmatically, I can set their `Tag` Property to a `Vector<int>^` to store their index. When the flyout closes, I just need to set the foreground to black again. It isn't the best way, but looks nice and works fine. Should I post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would've hoped `ListView->Refresh()` might do something like this but alas, no.

Instead I have to repopulate the whole `ListView` just to reset the selection since it's not a natively modifiable property. *(why?)*

```
listView1->Items->Clear();

ListViewItem^  listViewItem1 = (gcnew ListViewItem(gcnew cli::array< String^  >(2)
{
    L"Column 1",
    L"Column 2"
}, -1));
ListViewItem^  listViewItem2 = (gcnew ListViewItem(gcnew cli::array< String^  >(2)
{
    L"Column 1",
    L"Column 2"
}, -1));
ListViewItem^  listViewItem3 = (gcnew ListViewItem(gcnew cli::array< String^  >(2)
{
    L"Column 1",
    L"Column 2"
}, -1));

listView1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< ListViewItem^  >(3)
{
    listViewItem1,
    listViewItem2,
    listViewItem3
});
```

You can also do this entirely dynamically - this is just a static example.

Comment: Also a possible workaround, but it seems more resource intensive, especially as the list gets longer. In theory, it is a modifiable property as pointed out above. One should be able to just set the `SelectedIndex` property to `-1`, but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: Agreed. There's a lot of basic things like that which have no property access when they ought to.